# Adding specific number of zeros before a string

Tags: oracle

I have written this query

```
update cmart_m_branch 
   set code=concat('000',cmart_m_branch.code) 
 where length(code)=1.
```

But it is not working..it was updating with all zeros..column code should have only 4 characters. But it is working like this.... just I am changing the query.....

```
Update cmart_m_branch 
   set code=concat('00',cmart_m_branch.code) 
 where length(code)=2.
```

Why it is not working with the length 1 ..please suggest me..

Comment: What is the type defined for your column `code` ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `LPAD()` instead? [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions095.htm#SQLRF00663)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're after [`LPAD`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions095.htm#SQLRF00663):

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT '1' col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '12' col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '123' col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '1234' col1 FROM dual)
SELECT col1,
       LPAD(col1, 4, '0') new_col1
FROM   sample_data;

COL1 NEW_COL1
---- --------
1    0001
12   0012
123  0123
1234 1234
```

Of course, this is assuming that your cmart_m_branch.code column is of string datatype. If it's of number datatype then there is no use in doing the update - you should instead format the data on-the-fly when you're selecting it (or you could use a virtual column to do the formatting for you). This can be done using `to_char()`:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 12 col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 123 col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1234 col1 FROM dual)
SELECT col1,
       to_char(col1, '0999') new_col1
FROM   sample_data;

      COL1 NEW_COL1
---------- --------
         1  0001
        12  0012
       123  0123
      1234  1234
```

If you're absolutely dead-set on using concatenation (why?) then you can do it using a case expression:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT '1' col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '12' col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '123' col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT '1234' col1 FROM dual)
SELECT col1,
       CASE WHEN LENGTH(col1) = 1 THEN '000'||col1
            WHEN LENGTH(col1) = 2 THEN '00'||col1
            WHEN LENGTH(col1) = 3 THEN '0'||col1
            ELSE col1
       END new_col1
FROM   sample_data;

COL1 NEW_COL1
---- --------
1    0001
12   0012
123  0123
1234 1234
```

Comment: Column data type is string...we can write with concat also..can u please give example with concat

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the version with concatenation. Why would you possibly want to use that instead of LPAD (which exists for exactly your situation!); there's far less typing involved, plus the meaning is far clearer, making it easier to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Nothing like that.I want to know the wrong in my query...so I have asked .that's it

Comment: You didn't give any sample input and output data in your question; please update it to add that information in - that way, we might stand a better chance of working out what the issue might be. As things stand, I don't see any reason why your update would replace a single character with anything other than the single character prefaced with three zeros. Maybe the original character was a zero, making the updated column show four zeros?

Comment: @Boneist - perhaps the issue the OP didn't like is that the update resulted in `'000'` when the original value was `null`? This is something I would ask about in any case; perhaps `null`s should remain `null`? `lpad()` has the benefit of having this (desired, perhaps) behavior, while a simplistic concatenation does not. Your suggested solution for concatenation does have this (desired, perhaps) behavior too.

Comment: @mathguy but if the column was null, its length wouldn't be 1, so it wouldn't have been updated?

Comment: Right - I missed that! (I looked at the code, but then I read your solution, the comments, ...  by the time I wrote my comment I had forgotten the original code). My bad!

Comment: @mathguy at least I'm not the only one with a less-than-stellar short-term memory! *{;-) #ThatsMyExcuseAndImStickingWithIt

Comment: One more thought, for the suggested solution - I would add `where length(col1) < 4`. Otherwise values that are already four characters would be updated (overwritten) with themselves. The assignment itself may not add much overhead, but it will also generate undo and redo... best to avoid that.